# How to dynamically set zoom value on Google Maps API during initialization

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have code like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="hidden" id="zoom_data" value="8">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: $('zoom_data').val()
  });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the maps goes blank. I just want to dynamically set zoom locally, not from server. Any advice?

Comment: set it to... what?  You can either specify the zoom property when you create the map, or call `map.setZoom()` after you've created it.

Comment: Try this: `$('#zoom_data').val()`. Your selector was invalid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. You need to use document.getElementById() to get the value of the hidden field then convert it to number before using it as a zoom parameter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="hidden" id="zoom_data" value="8">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map;
 function initMap() {
    var zoom = document.getElementById('zoom_data').value;
    var nZoom = Number(zoom);
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: nZoom
  });
}

</script>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

hope it helps!